# What are good/established database backing strategies for logic programming in clojure

Tags: database, clojure, logic-programming

I'm having a hard time finding profound information on strategies to set up a (deductive) database for facts to be queried using a logic programming approach like [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic). Most examples to be found deal with facts created in memory.

A really nice library out there is [Cascalog](https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog). It sits on top of hadoop and abstracts away the map-reduce with a nice and intuitive query language inspired by datalog.

But Cascalog is hadoop only and I wonder if there are similar clojure solutions which go well with other types of databases, be it nosql or relational (deductive databases).

Comment: It seems like Rich Hickey may again have made something groundbreaking here. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

This blog post show how write relations that query from a data source:

http://tsdh.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/using-clojures-core-logic-with-custom-data-structures/

Using the ideas there, I was able to write relations to query from MongoDB and Redis.